# Virtual server for testing

Tags: php

I need to test some php code, what light-server can i install on my computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) for a quick install of Apache, mySQL, PHP and Perl if you use Windows.

There are a few of these kinds of applications for various OSs, such as Xampp for Linux and Mamp for Mac

Answer (score 1):

Well, on Windows or Linux (and probably Mac), I like Apache.  It might not be ultra-lightweight, but it is very configurable and has been solid for me in the past.

[Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/)

I forgot how confusing their pages can be at first.  I think this is the page you want, just make sure you get the right version for your OS:

[Download Page](http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi)

Answer (score 0):

A solution that has always worked for me is to download [Xammp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#641). Easy to install apache server for windows. Not exactly lightweight (comes with mysql, perl, filezilla) but can't be beat in terms of ease of use.